# Gradient stroke in PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to draw curves with gradient stroke color not fill color using JAVA PDFbox, anyone can help me with how to do that?

For filling shapes I'm using:

```
contentStream.clip();
contentStream.shadingFill(PdfUtils.createGradientColor(gradientFactors));

public static PDShadingType2 createGradientColor(GradientFactors gradientFactors) throws IOException {
    Color startColor = gradientFactors.getStartColor().getColor();
    Color endColor = gradientFactors.getEndColor().getColor();

    COSDictionary fdict = new COSDictionary();

    fdict.setInt(COSName.FUNCTION_TYPE, 2);

    COSArray domain = new COSArray();
    domain.add(COSInteger.get(0));
    domain.add(COSInteger.get(1));

    COSArray c0 = new COSArray();
    c0.add(new COSFloat(startColor.getRed() / 255f));
    c0.add(new COSFloat(startColor.getGreen() / 255f));
    c0.add(new COSFloat(startColor.getBlue() / 255f));

    COSArray c1 = new COSArray();
    c1.add(new COSFloat(endColor.getRed() / 255f));
    c1.add(new COSFloat(endColor.getGreen() / 255f));
    c1.add(new COSFloat(endColor.getBlue() / 255f));

    fdict.setItem(COSName.DOMAIN, domain);
    fdict.setItem(COSName.C0, c0);
    fdict.setItem(COSName.C1, c1);
    fdict.setInt(COSName.N, 1);

    PDFunctionType2 func = new PDFunctionType2(fdict);

    PDShadingType2 axialShading = new PDShadingType2(new COSDictionary());

    axialShading.setColorSpace(PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
    axialShading.setShadingType(PDShading.SHADING_TYPE2);

    COSArray coords1 = new COSArray();
    coords1.add(new COSFloat(gradientFactors.getX1()));
    coords1.add(new COSFloat(gradientFactors.getY1()));
    coords1.add(new COSFloat(gradientFactors.getX2()));
    coords1.add(new COSFloat(gradientFactors.getY2()));

    axialShading.setCoords(coords1);
    axialShading.setFunction(func);

    return axialShading;
}
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Likely possible by using the shading as a pattern (PDShadingPattern) colorspace as stroking color, like in the CreatePatternsPDF example. Sadly I don't have to time to implement this. The best would be to use PDFDebugger to compare with an existing file that uses a shading pattern.

Comment: Sorry can you explain more?

Comment: A pattern can be a tiling pattern (as in the CreatePatternsPDF example) or a shading pattern (no example yet). What I mean is that "shading" can be done in two ways in PDF, either like as a shading fill as you've shown, or as a shading **pattern**. Because a pattern is also a color, such a pattern can be used as a stroking color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already indicated by Tilman, you create a `PDColor` from your shading:

```java
PDShadingType2 shading = createGradientColor(...);
PDShadingPattern pattern = new PDShadingPattern();
pattern.setShading(shading);
COSName name = page.getResources().add(pattern);
PDColor color = new PDColor(name, new PDPattern(null));
```

Then you draw with that color, e.g.:

```java
try (   PDPageContentStream canvas = new PDPageContentStream(document, page)) {
    canvas.setStrokingColor(color);
    canvas.setLineWidth(5);
    canvas.moveTo(0, 0);
    canvas.lineTo(500, 500);
    canvas.curveTo2(500, 250, 250, 250);
    canvas.curveTo1(0, 250, 0, 0);
    canvas.stroke();
}
```

Assuming that gradient goes from red to green from 0,0 to 500,500, the result looks like this:

[image: screen shot]

*([DrawGradient](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/DrawGradient.java) test `testDrawWithGradientColor`)*